# Maxima solve equation

Tags: maxima

I am new to maxima.

Wanted to know how to extract the solution for solve? Example:

```
(%i1) soln: solve([x^2 - 9 =0], [x]);
(soln) [x=-3,x=3]
```

How to extract the values `-3` and `3` and assign them to some variables.
I know that if the solution had been

```
(soln) [-3,3]
```

then I could have used `soln[1]` and `soln[2]` to get the values `-3` and `3` respectively.

I hope I am able to express my doubt. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign the output of solve in maxima to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765715/how-to-assign-the-output-of-solve-in-maxima-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @SurentharP for the link to the solution. I searched SO but missed the answer that the link provides. For the above problem the solution is as follows:

```
soln: solve([x^2-9=0], [x]);
xvals : map(rhs, soln);
```

In this case `xvals` will store the values `-3` and `3`. The issue is solved.